# OnTriggerStay only applying to one object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im working on a AI combat system where each AI has a secondary collider with "Trigger" enabled. here is my script so far

```
    public float health = 100;
 public int isrunning = 1;
 public GameObject currenttarget;
 public int attackspeed;
 public int damage;
 public int newdamage = 0;
 void Start()
 {
     StartCoroutine(DoDamage());
     
 }

 public void TakeDamage(float x)
 {
     this.health = this.health - x;
 }

 public IEnumerator DoDamage()
 {
     isrunning = 0;
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(attackspeed);
     Debug.Log("loop");
     newdamage = damage;
     isrunning = 1;
 }



 private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
 {
     if ( other.gameObject.CompareTag("AI"))
         {
         other.GetComponent<Framework>().TakeDamage(newdamage);
         newdamage = 0;
     }

 }

 private void Update()
 {
     if (isrunning==1)
     {
         StartCoroutine(DoDamage());
     }
 }


 // Update is called once per frame
```

}

When I place three objects with this script where there damage is set to 5 and attack rate to 1, The result that I want out of this would be: A.100 B.100 C.100 (1 Second) A.80 B.80 C.80 However what I find is that the other.GetComponent().TakeDamage is only applying to one object at a time rather then being applied to the other two objects as I want. is this how the OnTriggerStay should be working? and if so are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: If I understand you correct what you do is: Have 3 objects with this script attached. Then you place 1 object (AI) in the range of these three objects => Of course all three objects will affect one and the same target AI object .... Or do I misunderstand your setup?

Comment: @derHugo well I want to allow this script to have it where every gameobject that has this can receive damage from every object which radius its in(the collider) and give damage to every object that's in its radius. In my setup none of these gameobjects have other scripts attached to them this is just meant to be my backbone that allows ai to give and receive damage. my setup has three cubes with this script where each is in the radius of the other two.Currently, this script is producing results where these game objects are only inflicting damage on one of its two neighbors

Comment: Are they all tagged correctly?

Comment: @derHugo yes. I can provided video/image of whats happening if that would help

Answer (score 0):

In my way, I suggest you to use a List of object, whenever the eneny attack(OnTriggerEnter) the player, you can push them to the list, then use the foreach loop in the Update Func to do some Function like take damage,... , after the enemy stop attack(OnTriggerExit) you can Pop its out of the List.